# I don't know how to fix ORA-04091 mutating trigger error

Tags: oracle, trigger, plsql, errors

I'm learning Oracle SQL, but when dealing with triggers I'm finding an error, that prevents me from updating values in that table.

The error is:

> error ORA-04091: table USUARIO.LINEAS is mutating, trigger/function may not see it ORA-06512: at "USUARIO.TRG_ACTUALIZARPEDIDO", line 5 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'USUARIO.TRG_ACTUALIZARPEDIDO'

I've learning about it, but can't find a solution or understand by myself what's the problem.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_actualizarpedido
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON LINEAS
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
    sumaImporteLineas NUMBER := 0;

BEGIN
    SELECT SUM(IMPORTE) INTO sumaImporteLineas FROM LINEAS WHERE NUMPEDIDO = :NEW.NUMPEDIDO;
    UPDATE PEDIDOS ped SET ped.TOTAL = sumaImporteLineas WHERE ped.NUM = :NEW.NUMPEDIDO;
END;
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can't `SELECT ...  FROM LINEAS` within a `FOR EACH ROW` trigger on `LINEAS`.

Comment: In addition to what @MichaelKutz said, you should not store in the database something that can be calculated by querying it (such as the total of order items).

Answer (score 1):

## ORA-04091

This is Oracle's way of saying:

> you really don't want to do that.

Here is my short-list of workarounds.

## Option 1

Use a `VIEW`.

This is the preferred method.

## Option 2

Use a `Materialized View`.

Yes, you can Fast Refresh SUM() on commit.

## Option 3

Use a TAPI (Table API). (a `Package`)

All DML operations must go through this `Package`; never against the actual table.

## Option 4

3-Trigger solution.  (This could be a single Complex trigger.)

Without proper locking, you could have "lost updates".

Even with proper locking, Dead Locks could occur.

Comment: You know what be interesting, Michael .. posting these 4 options as seperate answers . :)  Personally I'd smash the upvote for the view .. (YES) .. and that option 4 .. *yuck* (downvote)  :P   But very good, simple, yet concise answer regardless .. :)

Answer (score 0):

Within a trigger reacting to a change to a table, you cannot query the table itself. 
But you don't need to.

It looks as though you're trying to keep a running total based on changes to the value of IMPORTE.  For that, you need not one but *three* triggers:

```
/* Insert - Add New value */ 
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_actualizarpedido1
AFTER INSERT ON LINEAS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE PEDIDOS 
    SET TOTAL = TOTAL + :NEW.IMPORTE 
    WHERE NUMPEDIDO = :NEW.NUMPEDIDO ; 
END;

/* Update - Subtract the Old value, Add New value */ 
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_actualizarpedido2
AFTER UPDATE ON LINEAS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE PEDIDOS 
    SET TOTAL = TOTAL - :OLD.IMPORTE + :NEW.IMPORTE 
    WHERE NUMPEDIDO = :NEW.NUMPEDIDO ; 
END;

/* Delete - Subtract the Old value */ 
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_actualizarpedido3
AFTER DELETE ON LINEAS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE PEDIDOS 
    SET TOTAL = TOTAL - :OLD.IMPORTE 
    WHERE NUMPEDIDO = :OLD.NUMPEDIDO ; 
END;
```

Comment: You will get a problem if `TOTAL` or value of `IMPORTE` is `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

As already given in the other answers using a trigger for such task is not the preferred way of doing it. For the sake of completeness here a trigger based solution (not tested):

```
create or replace trigger trg_actualizarpedido
  for insert or update or delete on LINEAS 
  COMPOUND TRIGGER

  type NUMPEDIDO_t is table of LINEAS.NUMPEDIDO%type;
  NUMPEDIDOs NUMPEDIDO_t ;
  sumaImporteLineas NUMBER;

  before statement is 
  begin
    NUMPEDIDOs := NUMPEDIDO_t();
  end before statement;

  after each row is 
  begin
    NUMPEDIDOs.EXTEND;
    IF INSERTING OR UPDATING ('NUMPEDIDO') THEN
       NUMPEDIDOs(NUMPEDIDOs.LAST) := :NEW.NUMPEDIDO;
    ELSIF DELETING THEN
       NUMPEDIDOs(NUMPEDIDOs.LAST) := :OLD.NUMPEDIDO;
    END IF;
  end after each row;

  after statement is 
  begin      
    for i in NUMPEDIDOs.FIRST..NUMPEDIDOs.LAST LOOP
       SELECT SUM(IMPORTE) INTO sumaImporteLineas 
       FROM LINEAS 
       WHERE NUMPEDIDO = NUMPEDIDOs(i);

       UPDATE PEDIDOS ped SET ped.TOTAL = sumaImporteLineas 
       WHERE ped.NUM = NUMPEDIDOs(i);
    end loop;          
  end after statement;

end;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can not query the table that caused a trigger to fire inside the trigger itself. 
But in this case, I don't see any need to. You can use :NEW to access the values you're selecting from the table instead: